# python 3 add many list in one

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have several lists with the same number of elements, example:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2], [3, 3, 1, 1], [...], .....etc...
```

I would like to get a single list containing all the items in the listed lists, example:

[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, ..........]

How can I get this result in the simplest way possible?

I tried this way but I can not find a solution.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2], [3, 3, 1, 1]]

b = len(a)

for n in range(b):
    a[0] += a[n]
    print(a[0])
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1]

[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2]

[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1]
```

I would only use the last list produced without the repetition of the first list, but I can not correct it and extrapolate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward solution would use `extend` method of a list.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2], [3, 3, 1, 1]]
result = []
for aa in a:
    result.extend(aa)
```

I hope you will find Python's `itertools` interesting for this as well.

```
from itertools import chain

a = [[1, 2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2], [3, 3, 1, 1]]
result = list(chain(*a))
```

`*a` is basically unpacking the list for you.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a `reduce()` function that can be used like this:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2], [3, 3, 1, 1]]

import functools
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, a)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1]
```

---

This may be less efficient than modifying an element in-place, as in the question.  If you want to keep using that, the simple thing to do is to start with an empty list rather than re-using `a[0]`:

```
result = []
for e in a:
    result += e
print(result)
```